# Convert one item to lowercase before AD export

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export, tolower

In an ActiveDirectory Export I want the mail adresses in all lowercase, I know about `ToLower()` but I'm struggling putting it in the right place:

(Powershell)

```
Get-ADUser 
-SearchBase "OU=11-something,DC=somethingelse,DC=somethingelser" 
-Filter {somefilters} -Properties name,mail
|Select-Object  Name,(mail).ToLower()
| Export-Csv -Path "D:\Path" 
 -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Is it even possible with `Get-ADUser` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize the Select-Object output using a calculated property:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=11-something,DC=somethingelse,DC=somethingelser" 
-Filter {somefilters} -Properties name,mail
|Select-Object Name,@{N="Email";E={$_.mail.ToLower()}}
| Export-Csv -Path "D:\Path" 
 -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

See: [Select-Object Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)